# Affectation attribute with heritage

Tags: php, codeigniter, inheritance

I Have something like that :

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_CONTROLLER
{

public $user = 'Default';

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->user = 'Construct';

}

public function getUser() { return $this->user;}    

public function signIn()
{
    $this->user = 'SignUp';
    redirect('membre');
}   
}

class MY_Membre_Controller extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    if(!parent::isLogOn()) {
        redirect('accueil');
    }

}
}
```

in my application/core/MY_Controller.php

And in my controller, I have :

```
class Membre extends MY_Membre_Controller 
{

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function profil()
{
    echo 'login = ' . $this->getUser();
   }
```

So, someone can say me why user attribute has always 'Construct' value when I can the signIn() method and after it redirect me to Membre/profil ?

Comment: Why the triple  extension?

Comment: Like that membre can extends MY_Membre_Controller and in its constructor, it redirect automatically if i'm not logged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're code **always** goes through the constructor, but not always through the signIn method. After the redirection it all happens from scratch. So:

signing in:

- constructor sets user to 'construct'
- the signIn method sets user to 'signUp'
- redirection to 'membre'
- again, constructor sets user to 'construct'
- ...

Comment: You're welcome! :) You should probably consider implementing a slightly different login logic.

Comment: Why ? We can access to Membre only if we're logged. This is not logic ?

Comment: Yeah, that's the right logic, but you might not need that many extensions - I'd put the isLogged check in the constructor of the Membre controller, and that's it. However, if you have many more controllers than need that check, then it's perfectly acceptable to extend the logic into a parent controller.

Comment: Yes, some others controllers. It's the reason.
Thanks you @Shomz.